# Scala type inference and getting the more specific of two type parameters as method result

Tags: generics, scala, type-inference

What I'd like to do is define conditions over classes, including inheritance. If two conditions are and-ed (or or-ed), the result should be a condition over the more specific class, i.e. query conditions.
So if I have

```
class Parent
class Sub extends Parent
class SubSub extends Sub
```

a `Condition[Sub] and Condition[Parent] and Condition[SubSub]` should yield a `Condition[SubSub]`.
Conditions should also be contravariant since a condition over a Parent should also be a condition over a Sub. Thus I defined (the AnyRef is an additional, external constraint):

```
class Condition[-A<:AnyRef] {
  def and[R<:A, P>:R<:AnyRef](that:Condition[P]):Condition[R]=
    new AndCondition[R](this, that)
}

class AndCondition[-A<:AnyRef](left:Condition[_>:A], right:Condition[_>:A]) 
  extends Condition[A]
```

The typing of the AndCondition seems to be ok, since this

```
val a:AndCondition[SubSub] =
  new AndCondition(
    new AndCondition(
      new AndCondition(
        new Condition[Parent], 
        new Condition[Sub]), 
      new Condition[Parent]),
    new Condition[SubSub])
```

works. I had problems with the and method for infix calls and came up with the definition above, which also works:

```
val b: Condition[SubSub] = 
   new Condition[Parent] and 
     new Condition[SubSub] and 
     new Condition[Sub]
```

... kind of, since it stops working when and-ing a fourth condition:

```
val c: Condition[SubSub]=
  new Condition[Parent] and 
    new Condition[SubSub] and 
    new Condition[Sub] and 
    new Condition[Parent]
```

results in 'Nothing' inference:

```
error: inferred type arguments
[com.solvedirect.test.SubSub,com.solvedirect.test.SubSub,com.solvedirect.test.Parent]
do not conform to method and's type parameter bounds 
[R <: Nothing,R <: R,P >: R <: AnyRef]
```

"Reducing" the "and chain" by bracing together the first and second two conditions (i.e. (a and b) and (c and d)) makes it compile again.
I guess I took some wrong route but cannot see it. I'm sorry for the unspecific question title or if this has already been answered, but I couldn't find it, probably also due to lack of descriptive search terms.

Thanks for your time.

regards,

Messi

Comment: I've now tried to define the `and` method with an intersection result type as follows:
`def and[P<:AnyRef](that:Condition[P]):Condition[A with P]=new AndCondition[A with P](this, that)`
This seems to work but I'm not sure whether this has unintended side effects.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would like to put your attention of the fact that having a generic parameter that cannot be inferred is weird, because that does not contain any information about the data contained in the class. If it would, then it would be inferable.

When you do not assign the return type explicitely, a parameter can be inferred. Since infix operator (unless they end with :) in Scala are left associative, in this statement:

```
val c:Condition[SubSub] = new Condition[Parent] and new Condition[SubSub] and
  new Condition[Sub] and
  new Condition[Parent]
```

the compiler acts like this :

```
 ((new Condition[Parent] and new Condition[SubSub]) and
  new Condition[Sub]) and
  new Condition[Parent])
```

So you end up in the following situation:

- The first and between Condition[Parent] and Condition[SubSub] returns a type  that can't be inferred and that you didn't specify, so it is UnknownType1
- The second and the same: it is an and between UnknownType1 and a Condition[Sub], returning UnknownType2
- The third one takes an UnknownType2 and Condition[Parent]. Here the compiler can't check the constraint hold.

Please note that, in the case of the three operands and:

```
 val b: Condition[SubSub] =
new Condition[Parent] and
  new Condition[SubSub] and
  new Condition[Sub]
```

The compiler used the type of b to infer the type of the intermediate result (Parent and SubSub) and could check the bounds.

In the failing case, the compiler would need to infer twice the result, and it is not able to do that.

To get back to the initial comment, please also note that in the simple case, if you do not specify the result, the compiler fails as well, and this is normally a sign of poor design of your classes

val e = new Condition[Parent] and new Condition[SubSub]